# cannot resolve XSLFImageRendener and XSLFRenderingHint

Tags: apache, gradle, batik

I am using example of conversion from `pptx` to `svg`. I took the code from
[PPTX2SVG](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/PPTX2SVG.txt)

And added dependencies to my `gradle` application

```
compile "org.apache.poi:poi:$apachePoiVersion"
compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:$apachePoiVersion"
compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:$apachePoiVersion"

compile "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:$apacheBatikVersion"
compile "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:$apacheBatikVersion"
compile "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:$apacheBatikVersion"
```

However it is unable to resolve classes `XSLFImageRendener` and `XSLFRenderingHint`.

What dependencies are missing? As there is no imports in the example code I assume that it should be in `org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel` package

I am using `poi=3.16` and `batik=1.9`

Answer (score 0):

[The official note:](https://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html)

> Please note that XSLF is still in early development and is a subject
>   to incompatible changes in a future release.

So POI 3.16 is not compatible with 3.15.

I fix the compatibility and rewrite the PPTX2SVG.java at Github:

https://gist.github.com/ji-zhou/37f8a40fc1c889563736c82cb270921f