# Java Apache POI - PPTX2SVG dependency issue: cannot find XSLFImageRendener and XSLFRenderingHint

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

I'm working to get a running example for converting a *.ppt / .pptx* to ***.svg*** , using the [PPTX2SVG.txt](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/PPTX2SVG.txt) example mentioned in the [XSLF Cookbook](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html#PPTX2PNG) section on the Apache POI site.

I ran into a **maven dependencies issue**: `XSLFImageRendener` and `XSLFRenderingHint` cannot be resolved during the Maven build.

I'm using **Apache poi 3.17** , and I also tried the previous version, like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849335/cannot-resolve-xslfimagerendener-and-xslfrenderinghint), but it made no difference. Also, regarding this already existing question, I don't understand how I could use that compatibility fix which is mentioned there...

Does anybody know how this can be fixed ?

Thank you.

Comment: What maven dependencies have you currently specified? It's hard for us to advise you on what's wrong without those!

Comment: From <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> versions 3.17 .
- <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
- <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
- <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId> 

From <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId> versions 1.9
- <artifactId>batik-svggen</artifactId>
- <artifactId>batik-svg-dom</artifactId>
- <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId> .

Comment: As per [the Apache POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) (imagine that!) you need the `poi-ooxml` module for XSLF

Comment: Sorry about this misunderstanding, earlier when committing I pressed "Enter" too early, and then  re-edited the comment. 

So this is not the cause, as I DO have poi-ooxml included. all the three modules that I mentioned earlier.